# Parameters are null

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I have seen many similar questions and I have tried all the possible answers but my problem is still the same. Basically, I have the following ajax call.

```
var obj = {
    Duration: 12000,
    Errors: 2
};
var post = $.ajax({
    url: APIUrl,
    data: JSON.stringify(obj),
    type: "POST",
    cache: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json, charset=utf-8'
});
```

This is my View Model.

```
public class TargetBasedViewModel
{
    public int Duration{ get; set; }
    public int Errors{ get; set; }
}
```

And here is my controller.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage Post(TargetBasedViewModel test)
    {
        return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
```

The problem is that the parameter keeps coming as null.
I have used Fiddler to examine the request and it looks fine, all the attributes are there and I can even examine the JSON object and make sure that my values are actually being sent to the server. I have read many articles and even tried to add [ModelBinder] and [FromBody] to the parameter, but still no luck.
I have also tried to add this to my Application_Start()

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
```

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: I'm assuming from your question that the controller method is being invoked, it just has a null parameter? You might look at what the controller thinks the posted data looks like.

Comment: Yes, I actually have a breakpoint at the beginning of the Controller, everything loads fine except I keep getting a null value in the parameter. I wish I could "inspect" what is inside the controller's request but the serializer or model binder is supposed to take care of creating an instance of my defined class. So in other words, I do not know how can I examine what else is in the controller, for now I just use Fiddler and the request looks fine.

Comment: If you look at the ControllerContext, you can get to the HttpContext and from there to the HttpRequest.  You can then look at the Form collection or the QueryString collection.  Since you're posting, I think your data should be found in the Form collection, but since you're not using a serialized form, I'm not sure anything would be conveyed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6859371/ajax-post-to-asp-net-web-site-is-missing-parameters?rq=1) and the accepted answer.  It suggests that:

1. In order to POST, you need to set things up in the form of a FORM;
2. You need to do away with your dataType and contentType parameters.

I THINK I'VE GOT IT!  Your contentType parameter:

It needs to be "application/json;charset=utf-8"

You've got a COMMA after the "json".

Comment: Thanks @AnnL, I had it working before as a serialized form but I would like to POST a pure JSON, hence the JSON.Stringify. Other implementations that I have seen on other questions work fine using only JSON serialization.

Comment: Can you link to an example that you emulated?  Maybe we [the readership] can spot the difference.  Like, are you sure the examples included a POST?

Comment: OK, here is a good example where you can see that the data does not come from a form, rather is just a JavaScript object. [link](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Post-Data-to-MVC-4-WEB-API-80386405)

Comment: And here is another example [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10493111/asp-net-webapi-how-to-pass-object-with-getjson).

Comment: Nice one! I didn't spot the difference. At the moment I cannot try it because I am not at work ( I live in Finland so here it's quite late already ) but I promise to try this first thing tomorrow. Thanks for the effort and dedication. I will let you know how it goes.

Comment: Yes! That was exactly the problem. Now everything works perfectly! **Thanks a lot!** I am marking this as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Check the ModelState property on your controller. Deserialization errors are recorded there. You'll likely find out why deserialization failed.

Comment: Most likely there is an error in the deserialization even though the properties are primitive types and have the same name. However I do not get any notification. Tomorrow morning I will follow your suggestion. Thanks!

Comment: I have checked the ModelState.IsValid and it returns true. I managed to get an instance of the model using the [ModelBinder] annotation before the parameter, but the properties are set to zero. That is, when I post the data, for some reason the values are discarded and a new instance is created with the properties having "empty" values, in the case of int properties, this is a value of zero. I feel I am getting close...